# Do in-depth explanations help a hypochondriac?

Tags: psychology, prosocial-behavior

I have in my circle a person that is a hypochondriac and harbors fears regarding things the person considers me an expert in. So I often get asked questions like: "Can this make me sick?", "Can it cause cancer used in this or that way?" etc.

I don't always know how to react, should I try to placate the person's fear and gloss over certain potentially problematic corner cases, or should I go in-depth and explain every nook and cranny of the topic?

I usually go down into the weeds and try to explain in detail what would limit exposure and why. Sort of the "teach a person to fish" kind of approach. I consider this the most honest way. 
But it sometimes seems, that all the person wants to hear is: Don't worry about it. Don't do `<insert-commonly-known-worst-case>` and you'll be fine.

It honors me that I have so much trust put into my words, but sometimes I worry if I am doing the right thing. How can I support the professional treatment for this condition that person is already undergoing?

**EDIT:**
Just to be clear: There is no real substantial danger to the person. The topic is commonly regarded as not entirely clear and sufficiently scary even to the non-diagnosed hypochondriac, but scientifically and morally it is completely ok to say, don't use it too much and don't worry about it.